# Typedef equivalence for a pointer to struct

Tags: c++, typedef

I got this implementation of a struct:

```
struct NodoQ {
  Etype elem;
  NodoQ *sig;
};
```

Is this code below,

```
typedef NodoQ *PtrNodoQ;
PtrNodoQ ppio, fin;
```

the same as this one?

```
NodoQ* ppio;
NodoQ* fin;
```

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Comment: I think so, but why not ask the compiler?

Comment: I didn't try cause I got the second option everywhere in my code, and just didn't want to loose some time... so 
when using typedef NodoQ* PtrNodoQ.
PtrNodoQ becomes an alias of NodoQ* I guess is a way of avoiding the '*' and better readability...
thank you Michael and Mark

Comment: It's usually recommend (and I agree) to not use pointer typedefs in most cases, as they make your code harder to read.  C programmers know that `*` indicates a pointer already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this code below,
>
> ```
> typedef NodoQ *PtrNodoQ;
> PtrNodoQ ppio, fin;
> ```
>
> the same as this one?
>
> ```
> NodoQ* ppio;
> NodoQ* fin;
> ```

Yes, it's resulting in the exactly same pointer types for `ppio` and `fin`.

---

As for your comment

> *"I  didn't try cause I got the second option everywhere in my code, and just didn't want to loose some time... "*

You can easily test it:

```
void foo(PtrNodoQ p) {
}

void bar(NodoQ* p) {
    foo(p);
}
```

and

```
void baz() {
    NodoQ n;
    foo(&n);
    bar(&n);
}
```

compile all perfectly fine, without invalid type conversion warnings or errors.

---

Also you could have found the answer quickly in [this excellent reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) (emphasis mine):

> The typedef-names are **aliases for existing types**, and are **not declarations of new types**. Typedef cannot be used to change the meaning of an existing type name (including a typedef-name). Once declared, a typedef-name may only be redeclared to refer to the same type again. Typedef names are only in effect in the scope where they are visible: different functions or class declarations may define identically-named types with different meaning.

Comment: The fact that it compiles doesn't indicate that the types are identical, since there could be automatic conversions being applied. I prefer the answer that quotes the standard.

Comment: @MarkRansom _"since there could be automatic conversions being applied"_ The `NodoQ` struct from the OP doesn't indicate for such in any way. But yes I prefer the other answer also, that's why I've upvoted it as the 1st :)

Comment: I know, same as you, that there were no conversions. All I wanted to point out is that the code snippet you supplied couldn't *prove* it. Implicit conversions between related types happen all the time. I can't complain too much though, I didn't have any proof either.

Comment: @MarkRansom Probably a sample using template type deduction and using e.g. [`std::is_same()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) may give a better proof than what I've currently proposed for testing?

Answer (score 3):

In case you wanted the standardese, [dcl.typedef] states that:

> A name declared with the `typedef` specifier becomes a *typedef-name*. Within the scope of its declaration, a
>   *typedef-name* is syntactically equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated with the identifier in
>   the way described in Clause 8. A *typedef-name* is thus a **synonym** for another type. A *typedef-name* **does
>   not** introduce a new type the way a class declaration (9.1) or enum declaration does. *[ Example: after*
>
> ```
> typedef int MILES, *KLICKSP;
> ```
>
> the constructions
>
> ```
> MILES distance;
> extern KLICKSP metricp;
> ```
>
> are all correct declarations; the type of `distance` is `int` and that of `metricp` is “pointer to `int`.” *—end
>   example ]*

In your case, after

```
typedef NodoQ *PtrNodoQ;
```

The types `PtrNodoQ` and `Node*` are exactly the same and can be used interchangeably from there on out. The declarations `NodoQ* ppio;` and `PtrNodoQ ppio;` are exactly equivalent.